# ALSA capture default sound speaker

Tags: c, аудио, alsa

Разарабатываю визуализатор музыки и планирую получать данные прямо из системы, с помощью alsa

```
snd_pcm_open(&PcmDevice, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, SND_PCM_NONBLOCK);
```

Когда вызываю открытие PCM с именем "default" - то звук захватывается, если в компьютер не встален микрофон, но когда вставлен микрофон, то захватывается он, а не динамик.
Выдача aplay -L

```
null
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC883 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=10
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 4
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=11
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 5
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=12
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 6
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=10
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 4
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=11
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 5
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=12
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 6
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=4
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 4
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=5
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 5
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=6
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 6
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=10
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 4
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=11
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 5
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=12
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 6
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia
    USB Stream Output
usbstream:CARD=Device
    Usb Audio Device
    USB Stream Output
```

Можете подсказать как мне обратиться к карте динамика, когда есть микрофон?

Comment: Мне требуется получить устройство, чтобы слушать аудио данные из динамика, если я запущу в режиме playback, то я же буду проигрывать данные, а не вычитывать

Comment: Почему бы не использовать pipewire вместо вот этого всего?

Comment: Чтобы решить свою проблему решил использовать PulseAudio библиотеки